# Is it possible create list item in multiple list using SharePoint REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I have one requirement where I have to create a list item in List A and B.

I have to use single Rest Call to create the list item.

Is it possible to create the list item using the single REST API call in multiple list?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is not possible using SharePoint REST API, since REST API deals with single resource types. You can create a WEB API to accept the list item parameters and create separate instances in multiple predefined lists in your code.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Online (and on-premises SharePoint 2016 and later) and the Office 365 APIs implement the OData $batch query option, we can use $batch to achieve it.

Example: create item in two lists in one request.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#additemtolist").click(function(){
        addItemBatchRequest();
    });
})
function addItemBatchRequest(){
    var listA="ListA";
    var listB="ListB";

    var batchGuid = generateUUID();
    // creating the body
    var batchContents = new Array();
    var changeSetId = generateUUID();


    // add item to ListA
    var itemA = {
        "__metadata": { "type": GetItemTypeForListName(listA)},
        "Title": "Test"
    };

    var endpointA = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
                   + '/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\''+listA+'\')'
                   + '/items';

    // create the changeset
    batchContents.push('--changeset_' + changeSetId);
    batchContents.push('Content-Type: application/http');
    batchContents.push('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    batchContents.push('');
    batchContents.push('POST ' + endpointA + ' HTTP/1.1');
    batchContents.push('Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose');
    batchContents.push('');
    batchContents.push(JSON.stringify(itemA));
    batchContents.push('');

    // add item to ListB
    var itemB = {
        "__metadata": { "type": GetItemTypeForListName(listB)},
        "Title": "Test"
    };
    var endpointB = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
                   + '/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\''+listB+'\')'
                   + '/items';

    // create the changeset
    batchContents.push('--changeset_' + changeSetId);
    batchContents.push('Content-Type: application/http');
    batchContents.push('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    batchContents.push('');
    batchContents.push('POST ' + endpointB + ' HTTP/1.1');
    batchContents.push('Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose');
    batchContents.push('');
    batchContents.push(JSON.stringify(itemB));
    batchContents.push('');

    // END changeset to create data
    batchContents.push('--changeset_' + changeSetId + '--');
    // batch body
    var batchBody = batchContents.join('\r\n');
    batchContents = new Array();

    // create batch for creating items
    batchContents.push('--batch_' + batchGuid);
    batchContents.push('Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="changeset_' + changeSetId + '"');
    batchContents.push('Content-Length: ' + batchBody.length);
    batchContents.push('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    batchContents.push('');
    batchContents.push(batchBody);
    batchContents.push('');

    var batchBody = batchContents.join('\r\n');

    // create the request endpoint
    var endpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/$batch';

    var batchRequestHeader = {
        'X-RequestDigest': jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="batch_' + batchGuid + '"'
    };

    // create request
    $.ajax({
        url: endpoint,
        type: 'POST',
        headers: batchRequestHeader,
        data: batchBody,
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Successfully saved a batch request");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
// Get List Item Type metadata
function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
}    
function generateUUID() {
    var d = new Date().getTime();
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
        var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
        d = Math.floor(d / 16);
        return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x7 | 0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
}
</script>
<input id="additemtolist" type="button" value="AddItemToList" />
```

Article: [Make batch requests with the REST APIs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/make-batch-requests-with-the-rest-apis)